# on dom ready change html source using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tinymce

I'm stuck with tinymce align problem. When I align text content to image let say left content preview look ok but on rendering content I'm getting source like this

```
<p>
   <img width="205" height="154" alt="" src="/Content/uploads/images/mypic.jpg" left;"="">
</p>
```

now I want to change this snippet `left;"="` to `align="left"`using javascript so when user loads page and when js recognize snippet `left;"="` to automatically change to valid align property `align="left"`.

How to do that?

Comment: Wait "left;"="" is generated automatically?!

Comment: that's not valid html so I doubt you can access it with javascript

Comment: @TheCodeDestroyer exactly "left;"=" is generated automatically.

Comment: I would suggest to rather find root cause of this as parsing this html and replacing it is not safe and can produce corrupt html.

Comment: Are you sure that this ``left;"=""`` is not produced by some typo in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen anything like this `left;"="` generated automatically.  I'm not sure why it is generated, but you can **remove the `left` attribute and add `align` attribute to your image**.

Better try like this,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('img').attr("left")) {
      $(this).removeAttr( 'left');
      $(this).attr("align","left");
    }
 )};
```

Answer (score -1):

When I test this, you end up with an empty `left;"` attribute on the image, so you can do this:

```
if ($('img').attr('left;"') !== undefined) {
    $('img').attr('align', 'left');
}
```